# Prevent php from rounding small numbers

Tags: php, precision, floating-accuracy

Can php handle extremely small numbers without rounding them? For example, when calculating `exp(-99) + 1/2`, php compute this to be `0.5`. This is problematic if later I want to multiply the given result, instead of an extremely small number, it just gives half the number.

```
echo exp(-99) + 1/2 // Outputs 0.5
```

Comment: Php doesn't echo "1/2". Show real code and output  (a [mcve]) that highlights the problem.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart in my PHP echo returns `0.5`. @Joshhh read about float numbers - they have something like **PRECISION**. Read about that. And remember - float number is only in your head. 0.5$ it's 50 cents. Maybe you should change your idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're out of the range supported by floating point numbers.

On my platform (PHP floats are 64 bit) `echo exp(-99);` returns currectly `1.0112214926104E-43`

That's because the exponential part is wide enought to represent `e^-99`

But as I add... `echo exp(-99)+0.5;` I get `0.5`

The result you expect would be something with more than 50 decimal digits.

Double floats doesn't have a such large mantissa (usually the limit is around 18-20 decimals).

To answer your question, If you really need to do such math (*handle extremely small numbers without rounding them*) you could use **PHP's arbitrary precision math extension**:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php